# Obtain first and last month from a date of the form %Y - %Q

Tags: r, data-manipulation, zoo

I start with a data.frame where I transform column x to year and quarter.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

data = data.frame(x = c("2017-12-01", 
                       "2017-12-01", 
                       "2017-11-01", 
                       "2017-11-01", 
                       "2017-10-01", 
                       "2017-10-01"))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(x = as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                     x = as.yearqtr(x))
```

What I am trying to achieve is switch x with two new columns `start_at` and `end_at` where `start_at` takes the form `2017-first month of quarter-01` and `end_at` takes the form `2017-last month of the quarter-01`.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
data = data.frame(start_at = "2017-10-01", end_at = "2017-12-01")
```

Comment: The year of the date always going to be 2017?

Comment: @d.b I am following a template which states the end_at date as 2017-12-01

Comment: @JeanVuda The year can be whatever 2015, 2016, 2017 etc.
as.yearqtr(x) automatically changes the date to %Y  %Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(data$x), function(d)
    data.frame(start_at = as.Date(d),
               end_at = floor_date(x = as.Date(as.yearqtr(as.numeric(d) + .25)) - 1,
                                   unit = "months"))))
#    start_at     end_at
#1 2017-10-01 2017-12-01
```

You could also use the optional `frac` argument of `as.yearmon` to achieve it without `lubridate` (suggested in comments by G. Grothendieck).

> "frac" which is a number between 0 and 1 inclusive that indicates the fraction of the way through the period that the result represents

`frac = 1` indicates the end of the period (`Q4` in this case).

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(data$x), function(d)
    data.frame(start_at = as.Date(d), end_at = as.Date(as.yearmon(d, frac = 1)))))
#    start_at     end_at
#1 2017-10-01 2017-12-01
```